# How to upload two files with two different folders?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I'm trying to upload two files with two different folders, but it is actually uploading the only second file. how to resolve this one?

```
       private function _referal_image1( $type1, $type2, $img ) {
            $tempname1 = __static__ .'referral_logo'. __ds__ . $type1;
            $tempname2 = __static__ .'referral_background'. __ds__ . $type2;

            move_uploaded_file($img, $tempname1);
            move_uploaded_file($img, $tempname2);

            $file_name1 = 'referral_logo'.__ds__.$type1;
            $file_name2 = 'referral_background'.__ds__.$type2;

            $combine = array($file_name1, $file_name2);
            return $combine;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this line twice:

```
move_uploaded_file($img, $tempname1);
move_uploaded_file($img, $tempname1);
```

You can't move the same file twice. You need to copy the file the 2nd time

```
move_uploaded_file($img, $tempname1);
copy($tempname1 , $tempname2);
```

Comment: move_uploaded_file($img, $tempname1);
move_uploaded_file($img, $tempname2);

Comment: made changes like this, but still not uploading. only second file is uploading

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to use copy() the 2nd time. Moving it twice still results in only one file.

Comment: Not uploading bro, only 2nd file is uploading